# How do I solve this PHP stripe deprecation error?

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments

**I am getting this error when user try to take subscription**  What should i do to solve this problem?

ErrorException (E_ERROR)

> array_key_exists(): Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated.
> Use isset() or property_exists() instead (View:
> /home/u511498974/domains/sendcheetah.com/public_html/emailmarketing/vendor/acelle/cashier/resources/views/stripe/checkout.blade.php)

Previous exceptions

> array_key_exists(): Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated.
> Use isset() or property_exists() instead (0)

@LV98         $requestStartMs = Util\Util::currentTimeMillis();

```
    list($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders) = $this->httpClient()->request(
        $method,
        $absUrl,
        $rawHeaders,
        $params,
        $hasFile
    );

    if (array_key_exists('request-id', $rheaders)) {
        self::$requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry(
            $rheaders['request-id'],
            Util\Util::currentTimeMillis() - $requestStartMs
        );
    }

    return [$rbody, $rcode, $rheaders, $myApiKey];
}

/**
 * @param resource $resource
 * @param bool     $hasCurlFile
 *
```

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: Your answer is in the error itself: `Use isset() or property_exists() instead`

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by [PeterSH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13719067/petersh) in the comments beneath your question, is `property_exists()` the function you should use instead of `array_key_exists()` if you want to check for certain properties of a class/object.
To make sure your properties have values, use `isset()`.

This example would check, whether a property does exist in the class/object and contains something:

```php
// You probably want to check, whether that property exists and does have a value other than null.
if (property_exists($yourClass, 'propertyName') && isset($yourClass->propertyName) {
  ... // Do something in here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just changed

```
return array_key_exists($index, $this);
```

to

```
return array_key_exists($index, (array) $this);
```

It is working. I just type cast in Array datatype